# auto.arima: h irrelevant when xreg used

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

For all my forecast models (`arima` with Fourier, `tbats`, `ets` and `stlf` from the "forecast" package in R) I use the following:

```
model <- auto.arima(x, xreg=fourierf(x, K=y, h=52))
```

or

```
model <- tbats(x)
```

or

```
model <- ets(x)
```

or

```
model <- stlf(x)
```

then

```
forecast(model, h=52)
```

`h=52` as that takes my data to the end of this quarter.

I also used multiple regression separately.

I then decided to use ARIMA with the dummy variables I'd used in my regression model:

```
model <- auto.arima(x, xreg=dummy)
```

then

```
forecast(model, xreg=dummy, h=52)
```

However it doesnt matter if I use `h=52` or `h=1` or leave it blank, the forecast automatically seems to forecast the total length of my data set i.e. if I had 404 values it forecasted 404 values forward.

Just wondering why this happens and can I restrict the forecast to less?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `dummy` twice - once in fitting, once in forecasting. Thus, `dummy` presumably has 404 entries, as many as your historical series. `forecast()` correspondingly gives you one forecast per entry in `dummy`. (The forecasts will thus also depend on your *historical* covariate information, which you presumably don't want.)

Solution: feed only as many future covariate values into `forecast()` as you want forecasts for. (And make sure those covariate values actually *are* future values.)

Comment: So I need two tables of dummies. One to work out the model and second one with future dummies for the forecast? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's it!